# Include css in html, where should I put the css file?

Tags: go

I am trying (unsuccessful) to include my css into my html. I have the files (executable, html and css)in the same directory "/test".

I have done some research over the subject but I can not still include the css in a proper way. For what I already saw if I include the css file starting with "/" it is relative to root folder so to confirm where is the root folder of the program I printed it and it is pointing to "C:\Users\Filipe\Desktop\go\src\test>" where are all my files.

test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

type Page struct {
    Title    string
    NavItems []navItem
}

type navItem struct {
    Item string
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    page := Page{
        Title: "title",
        NavItems: []navItem{
            {Item: "item1"},
            {Item: "item2"},
        },
    }
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    t.Execute(w, page)
}

func testHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "/t directory test")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    fmt.Println(os.Getwd())

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mystyle.css">
    <title>{{.Title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    {{range .NavItems}}
        <a>{{.Item}}<a>
    {{end}}
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to register the handler that will serve the static files. Just do a search on how to serve static files with Go and plenty of answers, blog posts, etc. will come up.

Comment: Ok,  thanks for your guidance, that should be enough to get start searching and get my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

try to change -

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/mystyle.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test/mystyle.css">
```

That will should solve the problem.